# behaviour of tiny c++ structs

Tags: c++, struct

If I define a struct like:

```
struct tiny
{
    long t;
};
```

will it be handled like a `long` in terms of function arguments and alike,
in example would the parameter of:

```
void myfunc(tiny x)
{ ... }
```

be handled like a `long` parameter by actually being pushed on the stack?

So essentially, is the `tiny` struct only as large as a its sole member?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The memory consumption of a structure is at least the sum of the memory sizes of constituent variables.

However, the compiler may add padding between the variables or at the end of the structure to ensure proper data alignment for a given computer architecture

Comment: The standard has a special provision for classes that meet certain criteria, called PODs, in order to keep C compatibility. These types won't be padded, among other things. In this case, the `tiny` struct meets these criteria.

Comment: @dauphic No, a class/struct can be POD and still have padding.

Comment: @dauphic: PODs can have padding, just not at the beginning. See 9.2/17 in 2003.

Answer (score 7):

There's no guarantee of it, but at least with the compilers I've looked it it normally will be, yes.

Answer (score -1):

If you start adding virtual functions, it will increase by 4 bytes on most systems/compilers (and an extra 4 bytes for every interface you include). Generally speaking, the struct should be the same size as the contents unless the compiler has added extra padding as Aviv said.

Have a look at #pragma pack(n)for packing issues, at least in Visual Studio ([Microsoft page on pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

Comment: -1 I don't see any virtual functions in the OP's code. He was asking about a "tiny" struct; in fact, he is referring to PODs, although he doesn't know it yet. The type can be any width at least as great as the sum of the width of its members, for any reason. `#pragma` is non-standard.

Comment: I'm just saying that that is when it will start to get bigger, when it's non POD. That's why I said 'if'. No need to mark me down.

Comment: It can get bigger even when it is a POD. That's why I marked you down.